# Android - Get input (intent) from last activity to new activity but also have layout shown at the same time?

Tags: android, layout, button, android-activity

In the main activity of my app, it has the user enter their Name and click on a Shift number and click on submit. When they click on submit, it brings them to a new page (activity) and that page shows their Name and shift number again. But underneath, I want it to show the Timer (the timer that is provided in xml) but I don't know how to make it show the content of the layout and the input(intent) at the same time on one activity.

Help? Is there a way to collaborate the two?

This is my second activity's .java file:

```
package com.cyapps.downtimer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WinderDTActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            String opName = extras.getString(MainActivity.OP_NAME);
            String rChoice = extras.getString(MainActivity.RADIO_CHOSEN);
            textView.setTextSize(15);
            textView.setText( "\n\tOperator Name: " + opName + "\n\t" + rChoice );
            setContentView(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the second activity's XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is to have the second page/activity show the XML layout, and show the input that I got from the previous page as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should recreate the Name and shift number in the second activity. In order to accomplish this you need to:

In the main activity, put the intent params:

```
intent.putExtra("name", mName);
intent.putExtra("shiftNum", mShiftNum);
```

In the second activity, you need a layout that has space for the name and shift number (aside from the timer that you already have). This could be a TextView. Then, you fill up this TextView with the intent parameters:

```
TextView tv = findViewById(...);
tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name") + ": " + getIntent().getStringExtra("shiftNum"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that works.. let me edit the question with the codes. I forgot. Then can you please take a second look? Thank you!

Comment: Add a TextView element in your layout. Then in the Java code, you still setContentView(R.layout.second.xml). You then use findViewById to get the textView in your layout. And similar to what you did in your code, setText(...).

Comment: Can you help me code the portion you said "You then use findViewById to get the textView in your layout and similar to what you did in your code, setText()" I don't really understand how I'd go about doing that.